# Serve an HTML5 application as a Drupal Module

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I manage a Drupal 7 based website for my College's Student's Association.  Most of it is standard static pages.  Each year we run a room ballot for people to choose their rooms and this process will need an application to display current room allocations (in real time) and wiki style information about what the different rooms are like.

I need to be able to serve up static pages of HTML, javascript and css; bypassing the theming module.  I need the relative addressing in the html page which serves as the root of the application to work properly (e.g. "javascript/app.js" should pick up that file from within the module).  I then need to serve up json data from php using all the drupal APIs for permissions and database access etc.

I have a fair bit of experience in HTML, Javascript etc. and some in PHP, but I'm fairly new to Drupal module development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a custom module as you suggest, and separately put your HTML5 application in a sub-folder of the module. When it's accessed it will use the same relative paths as you'd normally expect so `javascript/app.js` will work if the file exists in the path under your HTML5 app's folder.

For the JSON data your custom module will look something like this:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['my/app/data'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_ajax_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  return $items;
}

function mymodule_ajax_callback() {
  $type = $_POST['type'];

  $nodes = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE type = :type", array(':type' => $type))->fetchAllKeyed();

  drupal_json_output($nodes);

  drupal_exit();
}
```

That code defines a menu path (using [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)) at `mp/app/data` which uses `mymodule_ajax_callback()` as it's page callback.

`mymodule_ajax_callback()` simply grabs all nodes from the database that match the `type` parameter passed in the AJAX `$_POST` and outputs their id and title in a JSON string to the page (which will then be returned as your AJAX response when you request `/my/app/path`).

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, there's some helpful stuff in there.  How does the index.html page get served up though?  I don't want to have to go to domain.com/Sites/All/Modules/RoomBallot/ to get it.  How do I make it appear at domain.com/RoomBallot/ and is it OK to have urls in the form javascript/app.js or should they be in the form /javascript/app.js

Comment: Thinking about it, it makes no difference where you put your HTML5 app; as your module will define the JSON menu path (`my/app/data`) this can be called from JS in the folder that you suggest as you normally would (`$.ajax({'url':'/my/app/data'});`). As far as the path `javascript/app.js` is concerned, Drupal wont' interfere with any paths/files that already exist so it'll be fine to call paths relative to your HTML app root, and not the site root.

Comment: Yeh, although I'd like the whole thing wrapped up inside the module so it lives in that folder.  That way things like updating Drupal are easier as all custom code lives in the sites directory.  I guess I could write a drupal function to handle requests to `/RoomBallot/{FolderName}/{FileName}.php` and then read out the file and return it

Comment: In that case I think yes, implementing either a custom menu item with a wildcard match or Drupal's inbound/outbound URL rewrite hooks would definitely be the way to go

Comment: One option would be to use the intall/uninstall hooks for Drupal to copy the files into the appropriate location?

Comment: Absolutely that could work, it does strike me as a bit 'messy' though...it feels cleaner to have the files on one place and serve them up from there but if you can get it working that way then it might be easier